# Iterating HashSet using JSTL

Tags: java, javascript, jstl, jsp-tags

I have a Set of Objects. I want to iterate these objects from set to display it on jsp using JSTL. It is working with List, but I need to use Set.

Is it possible with jstl to iterate a set ?

```
<c:forEach items="${pitches}" var="pitch" />
```

In above :  pitch has a set of object say `Set<employee>` ...

How can I iterate this employee set inside pitch ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes `<c:forEach>` works with all Iterable so Set should be good

Answer (score 1):

JSTL tag [`<c:forEach>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) works with any `Collection` implementation

**From docs:**

> The basic iteration tag, accepting many different collection types and
>   supporting subsetting and other functionality